# trouble with a while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, while-loop

Im trying to use a while loop with my util() function (its commented out at the bottom of the code). When I try to run the program, I am stuck in an endless loop where i dont get farther than where I'm console logging out "getProjects running"

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const _ = require("lodash");

axios.defaults.headers.common["Private-Token"] = "iTookMyPrivateKeyOut";
const user = "yshuman1";
let projectArray = [];
let reposExist = true;

async function getProjects() {
  console.log("getProjects running");
  await axios
    .get(`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/${user}/projects`)
    .then(function(response) {
      const arr = _.map(response.data, "id").forEach(repo => {
        projectArray.push(repo);
      });
      console.log(projectArray);
    });
}

function deleteRepo(projectArray) {
  console.log("array size", projectArray.length);
  const arr = _.map(projectArray).forEach(item => {
    axios
      .delete(`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${item}`)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("deleted project ID: ", item);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
}

function util() {
  getProjects()
    .then(() => {
      if (projectArray.length == 0) {
        reposExist = false;
      }
      if (projectArray.length < 20) {
        console.log("array is less than 20");
        reposExist = false;
      }
      deleteRepo(projectArray);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

// while (reposExist) {
//   util();
// }
```

Comment: Since it's asynchronous might be a better idea to use recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop is synchronous, while everything in any `.then` (or promise `await`) will be asynchronous. The initial thread will never terminate. Your code will simply queue up unlimited calls of `getProjects` which will only `console.log`.

The simple solution would be to figure out how often you want to call `util` (once a second? once every 5 seconds?) and `await` a `Promise` that resolves after that amount of time on each iteration.

```js
let reposExist = true;
function util() {
  console.log('running');
}

const resolveAfter5 = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000));
(async () => {
  while (reposExist) {
    util();
    await resolveAfter5();
  }
})();
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! The only other thing I had to do was add a line after calling util() to empty the array before looping again.